# NestJS, serialise bigint parameters in DTO

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, bigint

I have DTOs with parameters which have `bigint` type. Currently, when I receive these DTOs all these pramaters always have type `string`. Here is example:

```
@Get("")
async foo(@Query() query: Foo) {
    console.log(typeof Foo.amount) //string
}
```

My DTO:

```
export class Foo { 
    amount: bigint;
}
```

How to make it works and have `bigint` type of `amount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DTO:

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

//...

export class Foo { 
    @Transform(val => BigInt(val.value))
    amount: bigint;
}
```

Also in your controller:

```
import {ValidationPipe} from '@nestjs/common';

//...

@Get("")
async foo(@Query(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) query: Foo) {
    console.log(typeof Foo.amount) //should be bigint
}
```

**Whats Happening:**

ValidationPipe is a default pipe in NestJS that validates query property with the rules defined in Foo DTO class  using Reflection. The option [transform: true](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#transform-payload-objects) will transform ie; execute the function inside `@Transform` decorator and replace the original value with the transformed value (val => BigInt(val) in your case).

This will transform the stringified "bigint" to the primitive "bigint".

**EDIT:** Updated the function inside `Transform` decorator to match `class-transformer v0.4.0`

Comment: Working, thanks! But it must be @Transform(val => BigInt(val.value))

Comment: Oh nice catch..The 0.4.0 version was a breaking change. Updated the answer. https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I need to transform the dto in output (serializing the BigInt to string) is this work for this case too?